# create a task scheduler from the command line with python and run admin privilege

Tags: python, cmd, task, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I create manual tasks in the task scheduler like [here].(https://www.jcchouinard.com/python-automation-using-task-scheduler/)
I want to do this in cmd but how to choose admin privilege and send all parameters like path python or my file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my command line

```
schtasks /Create /TN "python cmd" /tr "C:\Users\autotest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe C:\Users\autotest\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py" /RL HIGHEST
```

But I get:
Invalid syntax. Mandatory option 'sc' is missing.
Type "CREATE /?" for usage.

I want to do this and set it to status ready.

Comment: You are missing the schedule. Add: /SC DAILY /ST 14:00 (that is daily at 2pm, add whatever schedule you want).

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the help text about creating scheduled tasks:

```
SCHTASK /CREATE /?
```

In that you will see "/RL HIGHEST" will run the job at the highest run level.

I'm not sure what you mean with your other requirements but, you should be able to find the answer in the help text.

Comment: I added  a comment about what I tried and what errors i got